# Changing datetime64[ns] data type to timestamp with am pm

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

I have data in this format ... 2022-11-29 16:15:02

When I run print(df.dtypes) command on my dataset, it shows me data type as datetime64[ns].

I need to change it to show in AM / PM format... like...

***"2022-11-29 04:15:02 PM"***

Please support.

I have tried using... `df['Order Completed At'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Order Completed At']).strftime('%I:%M:%S')`

But, I am getting error...

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: Use the `dt` accessor; i.e. `pd.to_datetime(df['Order Completed At']).dt.strftime('%I:%M:%S')`

Comment: see also: [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html)